# fatal error: interrupt.h: No such file or directory #include <interrupt.h>

Tags: c, ubuntu, compiler-errors, header, include

I receive the error in the title after running the code below.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
        printf("hello World!\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

ADDITIONAL INFO:

header stdio.h is included in usr/include directory.

gcc compiler.

using latest Ubuntu Operating System.

C program.

file name binaryWords.c

command line: "gcc binaryWords.c -o BinaryWords."

ERROR MESSAGE FULL:

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/stdio.h:11:0,
                 from binaryWords.c:1:
/usr/local/include/thread.h:11:10: fatal error: interrupt.h: No such file or directory
 #include <interrupt.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

How can I fix this error?
Why is interrupt.h needed?

Comment: What compiler is it?

Comment: Using Ubuntu.
Have installed build-essential.

Comment: gcc compiler in ubuntu

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code here. Your process for compiling and running it must be wrong.

Comment: How do you invoke the compiler?

Comment: gcc prog.c -o Prog

Comment: In file included from /usr/local/include/stdio.h:11:0,
                 from binaryWords.c:1:
/usr/local/include/thread.h:11:10: fatal error: interrupt.h: No such file or directory
 #include <interrupt.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.

Comment: `binaryWords.c` ? You have never mentioned it.

Comment: It seems you have installed your own version of GCC in a non-standard location. Are your `PATH` set up correctly?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I installed the gcc via sudo apt-get install -V gcc

Comment: binaryWords is the program name, updated the question.

Comment: by the way, a " " " is missing. Should be `printf("hello World!\n");`. I would try to reinstall the gcc again, seems to corrupted thread.h or interrupt.h is missing.

Comment: `/usr/local/include/stdio.h`... That is *not* the standard location of a system header file on Ubuntu. That means there's something you're not telling us, perhaps something you don't remember doing? If you run `which gcc` what do you get?

Comment: @TomKuschel how should I do that ? may you please write a process for that as a possible answer?

Comment: I do not have interrupt.h in usr/include directory.

Comment: @Reinstall: Sorry, I do not run Ubuntu, but I think there are tutorials or Ubuntu forums where you find how to first remove the compiler and afterwards reinstall it. As seen above, run `which gcc` and we know where the gcc is installed into.

Comment: Uninstalled, reinstalled. Same problem, please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ubuntu system there is directory usr/include and usr/local/include. I had a header stdio.h for a xinu embedded system which implemented a missing interrupt.h header located in usr/local/include, hence "interrupt.h" not found error. In usr/include is the standard C library with the standard stdio.h. Once I removed the headers in usr/local/include the simple helloWorld program compiled and I was able to run the program.

possible conclusion, GCC compiler searches in usr/local/include directory before searching in usr/include directory.